# Создание таблицы в mySQL (Ошибки в строках)

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброго всем кодинга.
Почему так происходит? (см.код)
И как создать таблицу именно с такими параметрами?
Почему `TIMESTAMP` не проходит?
почему `поле ASC` не проходит?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    `counterdata`(
    `rec_id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rec_ts` TIMESTAMP(8), // не работает!
    `counter_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `counter_data` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    `sender_ip` INT(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (rec_id), (rec_id ASC) //так не работает
    PRIMARY KEY (rec_id) //а так работает
    )
    TYPE=MyISAM // убираю, работает
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Comment: Для типа "TIMESTAMP" не нужно указывать длину, "sender_ip` INT()" - или укажите длину, или уберите скобки и "ENGINE=MyISAM", а что вы хотели сделать с "rec_id ASC" - я так и не понял

Comment: @Deonis , про `TIMESTAMP` смутила статья  
http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html
А от хочу `ASС` сортировка же.
http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_Create_table.php

Comment: что-то вы намешали: и SQL Server, и MySQL. Тут бы определиться не мешало бы.

Comment: @Deonis Спасибо большое! Я почитал, действительно от SQL Server'а приляпалось!
Убрал `rec_id ASC` поставил `ENGINE=MyISAM` - Всё заработало!
Обычно руками создавал (Navicat), а тут как-то захотелось автоматизировать процесс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот рабочий вариант ([см. на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbe81/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    `counterdata`(
    `rec_id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rec_ts` TIMESTAMP(6),
    `counter_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `counter_data` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    `sender_ip` INT(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (rec_id ASC)
    )
    Engine=MyISAM
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

что пришлось исправить:

1. timestamp — максимальная размерность = 6: [MySQL 5.6.4 and up expands fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)
2. asc/desc в описании `primary key` — работает. только у вас два раза один и тот же столбец был упомянут и синтаксис неправильный: несколько столбцов должны быть перечислены через запятую внутри **одной** пары скобок.
3. `Engine=MyISAM` — `engine`, а не `type`.
4. убрал дубликаты «работает/не работает», как взаимоисключающие.